# Regex capturing series of alphanumeric and numeric characters into an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not good at regex patterns, I can get everything inside the curly parenthesis with {(.*?)} but I cannot split them.

Suppose I have a string like this

```
{y12.13bb15.16}
```

**How do I capture it like this into an array:**

```
['y', '12.13', 'bb', '15.16']
```

although in the end essentially I wanna create an object like this:

```
{"y": 12.13, "bb": 15.16}
```

Comment: So in your data letters will always be keys and floating numbers will always be the values of your object?

Comment: @devius Letters will always be keys, and numbers will always be the values but they don't have to be floating.

Comment: This is not duplicate I do not want the "." captured seperately in the array.

Comment: Interesting hammer, as that dupe does not deal with other characters like `{}` as well as the floating point component.

Comment: You don't need the explanation for why this isn't a duplicate.  It just clutters the question.

Comment: @chrisz Okay! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`([\d\.]+|[^\d{}]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ImrcBK/1)

```js
var rx = /([\d\.]+|[^\d{}]+)/g
s = '{y12.13bb15.16}'

k = s.match(rx)
console.log(k)

// And now to convert to your desired object
var final = {}

for (i = 0; i < k.length; i += 2) {
  final[k[i]] = k[i+1]
}

console.log(final)
```